# Changing Text component value in runtime

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to get a `<Text>` component in the view and edit its value in runtime.

What I tried:

```
<Text ref="SignInMessage">qqq</Text>
```

Then to get and change the text I do `this.refs.SignInMessage.props.children = err.message` but it doesn't change.

I also tried:

```
<Text>{this.SignInMessage}</Text>
```

And then `this.SignInMessage = err.message;` but it also doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use state to update the value

```
this.state({ SignInMessage: '' }); // initialize

this.setState({ SignInMessage: 'bl bla'}); // update

<Text>{this.state.SignInMessage}</Text>
```

Comment: In what function do you call `this.state()`? The ctor? Because I'm getting `this.state is not a function` error.

Comment: OK, I did `      this.state = {
        SignInMessage: ''
      };` and now it works, thanks.